# Sentence: A clear alpha and beta state?

Tags: grammar

I am writing my thesis in English.
The full sentence I want to express is,

- The results showed a clear alpha state and a clear beta state

I am trying to use short sentences.

Can I write like one of these sentences? Which one is proper?

1. The results showed a clear alpha and beta state
2. The results showed clear alpha and beta states
3. (other??)

Comment: This is okay: *The results showed clear alpha and beta states*. I would maybe say: *The results showed states that were clearly either alpha or beta.* More words but perhaps clearer.

Comment: Brevity may be the soul of wit, but in academia, clarity better fits the remit.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat Those sentences are not as precise as the original (assuming edits haven't altered the original).

Comment: Your original is clearest and the one I'd choose, though you can omit the first 'state' without  dropping precision.